# Rails model method with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created an app where users can vote to polls. I started from [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/polling-users-rails/) and then modified it to my needs.

poll.rb:

```
has_many :vote_options, dependent: :destroy
has_many :votes, :through => :vote_options
```

vote_option.rb:

```
belongs_to :poll
has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
```

vote.rb:

```
belongs_to :vote_option
belongs_to :user
```

user.rb

```
has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
has_many :vote_options, through: :votes
```

A user can only vote once. To check if a user voted I have on user.rb:

```
def voted_for?(poll)
  vote_options.any? {|v| v.poll == poll}
end
```

I added then a column `delegated` to `votes` table. Now want to restrict the method `voted_for` only to votes for which delegated is false.

So I tried:

```
def voted_for?(poll)
  vote_options.where(:delegated => 0).any? {|v| v.poll == poll}
end
```

which returns:

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'vote_options.delegated' in 'where
>   clause': SELECT `vote_options`.* FROM `vote_options` INNER JOIN
>   `votes` ON `vote_options`.`id` = `votes`.`vote_option_id` WHERE
>   `votes`.`user_id` = 4 AND `vote_options`.`delegated` = 0

so I tried:

```
def voted_for?(poll)
  vote_options.votes.where(:delegated => 0).any? {|v| v.poll == poll}
end
```

which returns:

> undefined method `vote' for VoteOption::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f002ad28be8>

Which I don't understand as I have the association in place.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow completely [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/polling-users-rails/) which is you mentioned in your post then it will be

```
def voted_for?(poll)
    votes.any? {|v| v.vote_option.poll == poll}
end
```

See this [`existing repo`](https://github.com/bodrovis/SitePointPoller/blob/master/app/models/user.rb#L29)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the method on tutorial with vote_options was working too so I did not check the repo. I should have thought about it before.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood associations

currently you are calling `vote_options.votes`, that's wrong practically.

as `vote_options` return collections of records, and you can't call `.votes` for collection it will works with single record as associations is vote_option has many votes, it means one to many not many to many.

for your case you can try

```
def voted_for?(poll)
  votes.where(:delegated => 0).any? {|v| v.poll == poll}
end
```

if you still have any confusion go through [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)